# SwiftUI List not updating when changing data in sub-view

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am developing a simple App in SwiftUI where I show a list of persons with the possibility for navigating to the persons details and then editing those. I am using two ViewModels for that `PersonListViewModel` and `PersonViewModel`. Mainly, `PersonListViewModel` includes an Array of `PersonViewModel`. In my List View, I am doing the following:

```
struct PersonListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var personListViewModel: PersonListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(personListViewModel.personViewModels) { personViewModel in
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailView().environmentObject(personViewModel)){
                            Text(personViewModel.person.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Persons")
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine on the surface, but if I change anything in the view `PersonDetailView` by using the EnvironmentObject `personViewModel`, this change is not reflected when coming back to the list view. If I go back to the detail view though, it is correctly shown the changed information.

I start to doubt my hole MVVM architecture (Coming mainly from an OO background...).

Therefor, I am curious if I am missing something obvious, why the list view is not updating or if there is a fundamental flaw in my architecture.

Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: Have you used @Published for the personViewModels property in your view model?

Comment: Yes, `final class PersonListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var personViewModels = [PersonViewModel]()`

Comment: What kind of changes are you doing in your source? Adding/removing records in personViewModels array?

Comment: I am changing the name of a person, which is a property of `Person`, which lives in a published var in `PersonViewModel`: `final class PersonViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var person: Person`

Comment: This leads to this layered architecture where I have a `PersonListViewModel`, which includes a published array of `PersonViewModel` which then includes the model itself as a published property. Which I am now questioning: Is this really "Best Practice" when it comes to MVVM?